# Join and show latest Event

Tags: sql-server-2008, join

I need to generate a related of all "Tickets" that is open and with status "Analysis",i need to do a join in two tables.

The first one:

```
 SELECT TOP 1000
       [nsu_sugestao]
      ,[num_sugestao_papel]
      ,[edv_promotor]

  FROM [NovoCLIC].[dbo].[Sugestao]
```

Exemplo of this select:

```
nsu_sugestao    num_sugestao_papel  edv_promotor
1               372759              92602045
```

In this one, `num_sugestao_papel` is the number of the ticket, `edv_promotor` is the person the owns it.

The second one:

```
 SELECT TOP 1000
       [iClic]
      ,[iStatus]
      ,[dtDateCreated]        
 FROM [NovoCLIC].[dbo].[T_STATUS_CLIC]
```

Exemple:

```
iClic   iStatus     dtDateCreated
1       1           1999-01-25 13:33:00.000
```

The `iClic` is the ticket number, the `iStatus` is the status currently and `dtDateCreated`.

I need to show all Tickets the the last status is analysis, the status analysis is the number 2 in iStatus column, i don't need the tickets that already are in different numbers than 2.

```
SELECT TOP 1000 [nsu_sugestao]
    --  ,n.num_sugestao_papel
    --  ,n.edv_promotor
    --  ,s.iStatus
    --  ,s.dtDateCreated

 -- FROM [NovoCLIC].[dbo].[Sugestao]
 -- with     
   --  select s.dtDateCreated,MAX(s.EventDate)latestDate
--   from  [NovoCLIC].[dbo].[T_STATUS_CLIC] s
 --  right join [NovoCLIC].[dbo].[T_STATUS_CLIC] s on [NovoCLIC].[dbo].[Sugestao] =
```

I'm trying something like this, but I'm getting a lot of errors.

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Your question is not clear, I even tried after mofiying your original post.  For your requirement "to show all Tickets the the last status is analisis,the status analisis is the number 2 in iStatus colum", you do not need to join with another table as clause "Where iStatus=2" will retrun all Tickets having status 2.  Or you want to know, how to use CTE?

Comment: Invalid Column name in the (s.EventDate)
In the s-iStatus and the other,the 4 is getting the error “The multi-part ”identifer “s.iStatus could not be bound.”(This is probably because its not finished yet).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code given below and provide us feedback

```
SELECT
       S.[nsu_sugestao]
      ,S.[num_sugestao_papel]
      ,S.[edv_promotor]
      ,T.[iClic]
      ,T.[iStatus]
      ,T.[dtDateCreated]
FROM [NovoCLIC].[dbo].[Sugestao] S
INNER JOIN [NovoCLIC].[dbo].[T_STATUS_CLIC] T on S.nsu_sugestao = T.iClic
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
           [iClic]
          ,Max([dtDateCreated]) As LatestDateCreated
    FROM
        [NovoCLIC].[dbo].[T_STATUS_CLIC]
    GROUP BY
        [iClic]
) TM ON T.iClic = TM.iClic AND T.dtDateCreated = TM.LatestDateCreated
WHERE
    T.iStatus = 2
```